# Android camera won't stop autofocusing

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, camera

I am setting the focus mode to `FocusModeAuto` and then set the camera parameters.

Then I call `Camera.AutoFocus()`, get the result from the callback and start recording with a `MediaRecorder`.

The problem is that the camera keeps auto focusing on its own as if its in mode `FocusModeContinuousVideo` or `FocusModeContinuousPicture`.

I am having this issue on a LG K20 V phone, but I don't have this issue on older phones.

I tried setting the focus mode to `FocusModeFixed` after I get the focus I want to try and lock it in place, but that mode makes it jump the focus to a far distance and not the distance I auto focused to with my previous calls.

How can I lock the focus to the auto focus I previously obtained or set the focus directly so that I can have full control of it?

Also while it does the auto focuses I didn't request. The `OnAutoFocus()` callback is not being called.

Comment: If the device supports the auto-focus, you could try to use `cancelAutoFocus` to cancel any auto-focus function in progress. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#cancelAutoFocus()

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I tried that, it only stops when I explicitly started the current auto focus. If I try to spam the cancel, it throws an error saying it can't cancel it. Also even if it worked, it would be a race condition. Thanks tho.

Comment: The auto-focus needs some requirements. You could check it. It would be helpful. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback)

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I don't have an issue getting autofocus to start.

Comment: Could you share the function and event code that you are using